# Passing a value from php to javascript when they're in separate documents

Tags: php, javascript, variables

This javascript function is being triggered correctly when the variable's value is declared in the php within the same document and then passed to the php, but I'm having trouble doing this when the value is passed from a separate php document.

```
var session = '<?php echo $t; ?>';
if (session == "login_failed") {
    loginFailed();
}
```

It works when I declare the value in the same document like this:

```
<?php 
 $t="login_failed"; 
?>
```

But it doesn't work when I declare the value in the 2nd document (login-exec.php) like this:

```
<?php 
 $t="login_failed"; 
 echo $t;
?>
```

---

EDIT -
This is for the log in form, which is posted with login-exec.php *(action="login-exec.php" method="post")*. If the query on that page is successful then they are redirected to their account page, but if the query fails I want to trigger this function (instead of what I'm currently doing, which is to redirect them to another page with an error message)

Comment: Gonna need more code than that. What do you mean by "passed from a separate php document?" Are you using include or what?

Comment: You're including a page which `$t` is residing in it?

Comment: @imkingdavid This is for the log in form, which is posted with the 2nd form, login-exec.php *(action="login-exec.php" method="post")*. If the query on that page is successful then they're redirected to their account page, but if the query fails instead of redirecting them to another page with an error message I want to trigger this function on the login page (I just updated my question to explain this :-)) I'm assuming that you probably don't need to see the code for all that, but I'd be happy to post it if it would be helpful.

Comment: @MahanGM: No, should I? If a function fails on the php document this gets echo'd back to the original document. I know that I can echo messages and minor javascript functions (like alert) that way, so I'm assuming that I should be able to echo a value that way too

Comment: How do you pass `$t` to the first document? The only way to pass variables is to put them in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` methods.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean that I need to use GET in the 2nd document (login-exec.php) to pass $t to the login page if the function failed? If so, 2 questions - I know that certain variables can be declared to equal the value in a php file, so I'm confused when that's ok and when you need to use GET/POST. Also, would I use it the same way I do in an HTML form (even though login-exec.php isn't a form)?

Answer (score 1):

I usually put something like this in my main document

```
<script>

   function get_your_data() {

     var yourvalue = "<?php echo $your variable ?>";

     return your_data
   }

</script>
```

Then call the function in another document by calling, `get_your_data()`, it will be available in your external js document.

You can also use classes, and constants.

Comment: I'm not quite how to apply this in my situation. This is for the log in form, which is posted with the 2nd document (login-exec.php). If the query on that page is successful then they are redirected to their account page, but if the query fails I want to trigger this function on the login page (instead of what I'm currently doing, which is to redirect them to another page with an error message